# Power with successor arithmetic - how to prevent an infinite loop? [Prolog]

Tags: prolog, exponentiation, successor-arithmetics

I have been thinking over this the whole day. 
I finally admit, I do not understand Prolog as good as I thought.

At the start of the day, I had trouble implementing a successor arithmetic, which multiplies 2 s-Numbers, which structure is this:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)):-nat(X).
```

My first try was this:

```
 mul(0,_,0).
 mul(s(F1),F2,P):-mul(F1,F2,Tmp),add(F2,Tmp,P)
```

which worked, but the query `mul(X,Y,s(0))`  ended in an infinite loop. Why? 
I have read the following post: [Prolog successor notation yields incomplete result and infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139640/prolog-successor-notation-yields-incomplete-result-and-infinite-loop)

What I understood out of it: If I call mul before calling add, and I have variables in the mul/3 predicate which are NOT used in both mul/3 calls, Prolog tries to find new possibilties for the variables it did not bind. Therefore it goes into an infinite loop.

To solve the problem, I called add first:

```
mul(0,_,0).
mul(s(F1),F2,P):-add(F2,Tmp,P),mul(F2,F1,Tmp).
```

That did it.
Then i tried to implement the power function, and thought "Well, that's easy now, first try would be:

```
pow(_,0,s(0)).
pow(B,s(E),R):-pow(B,E,Tmp), mul(Tmp,B,R).
```

But, I have to put mul first to prevent the left-recursion of R and Tmp.

Easy!"   Boy, I was so wrong.
I have no idea how to implement it without getting in an infinite loop, even if I put the mul in front.

Any advice is highly appreciated. You can save my saturday work effort and boost my self-esteem! Thank you in advance.

Edit: Added my missing sum predicate:

```
add(0, Y, Y).
add(s(S1), S2, s(Sum)):-  add(S1,S2,Sum).
```

Comment: Related: [Power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9741582/772868).

Comment: The improvement in `mul/3` is caused by two different changes: exchanging goals **and** exchanging the arguments in `mul/3`!

Comment: Oh wow it's you. I read your explanation several times, yet I would lie if I said that I have fully understood it. I still don't know how exactly you figured out that you have to change the arguments.

Comment: For exchanging arguments, see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27202175/772868).

Comment: Thanks! So by rotating the order of the arguments within a predicate, I can increase/control it's termination condition. That does not work for power though, since B^E  != E^B.

Comment: Yes - the way you ask me this, I feel pretty stupid :(

Comment: Now, try the same trick again!

Comment: Well..I did try that same trick. I just can't pull it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want that the following termination conditions hold:

```
pow(B, E, P) terminates_if b(B), b(E).
pow(B, E, P) terminates_if b(P).
```

or briefly

```
pow(B, E, P) terminates_if b(B), b(E) ; b(P).
```

We cannot demand more than that. More than that would be `b(B)` alone or `b(E)` alone. But in those cases we need infinitely many answers that imply non-termination. Of course, we could take a definition that is always terminating, and that does succeed for all test cases, like

> pow(_B, _E, _P).

Alas, that definition also succeeds for any other case we **do not want**. So unless you will only get tested for success, you have to take a more elaborate definition.

Another way to avoid non-termination would be to resort into another definition of the natural numbers. Using [`library(clpz)`](https://github.com/triska/clpz) (SWI's `library(clpfd)` is a weaker precursor)

```
pow(B, E, P) :-
   B #>= 0,
   E #>= 0,
   P #= B^E.
```

But currently, we stick to successor arithmetics. CapelliC already gave you a definition that terminates for `b(B), b(E)`. So let's try to improve it! One way is to somehow use `P` to restrict the number of inferences to a finite number. A way to do this, is to consider relations between the arguments.

Are there any interesting relations between the arguments of `pow/3`? I really would like that:

> b<sup>e</sup> ≥ e, b<sup>e</sup> ≥ b for e, b ≥ 0

That is *almost* true. It holds in fact by adding b ≥ 2.

Just to be sure I will check that I am not completely wrong, I will try this out<sup>1</sup>:

```
?- M #= 10^150, [B,E,P]ins 0..M, P #= B^E, B #>= 2, P #< E.
false.
```

I will consider this a proof, although it isn't one.

Now for the definition. The idea is to handle the general case by adding additional arguments to limit the number of recursions. One limit `LP` for `pow` and one limit `LM` for `mult`. These arguments are separated by extra spaces to make clear where they have been added.

```
pow(_, 0, s(0)).
pow(0, s(_), 0).
pow(s(B), s(0), s(B)).
pow(s(0), s(s(_)), s(0)).
pow(B, E, P) :-
   B = s(s(_)), E = s(s(_)), P = s(s(s(s(_)))), 
   powx(B, E, P,     P, P).
%                    ^^^^^ added arguments to limit pow and mult

sum(0, M, M).
sum(s(N), M, s(K)) :-
    sum(N, M, K).

mul(0,_,0,_).
mul(s(F1),F2,P,    s(LM)) :-
   mul(F1,F2,Tmp,    LM),
   sum(Tmp, F2, P).   % note: arguments exchanged!

powx(_,0,s(0),    _, _).
powx(B,s(E),R,    s(LP), LM) :-
   powx(B,E,Tmp,     LP, LM),
   mul(Tmp,B,R,      LM).
```

For the simple case `pow(b,b,f)` the overheads should be minimal. For the new case, `pow(f,f,b)` the overheads might be reduced by lowering the limits somehow.

---

<sup>**Footnotes**</sup>

1 I only tried it out with 10<sup>150</sup>. No general proof. Let's hope its fine. For some reason, larger values produce a stackoverflow™. It's the last goal `P #< E` which induces a lot of recalculations. Otherwise it works up to 10<sup>10<sup>7</sup></sup>.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still have plenty to learn in Prolog. There is no way I would have come up with this, taking my current state of understanding of Prolog.
I will try to read this again and again until I finally know how transfer the obtained knowledge on other cases.

Comment: @InDaPond: The example is a little bit too complex to start with, two independent limits need to be maintained. I'd say, that [2^x](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9741582/772868) would have been a better exercise.